# Python Flask alongside with node.js

Tags: node.js, flask

I have a Python Flask application and I'm about to start implementing websockets and I wan't to have all this done in node.js of several reasons;

Node.js use less overhead and I like the idea of separating the more more heavy logic from the more traffic intensive parts.

node.js seem to have better support for websockets and being more mature.

And I might later on move the node.js to a separate server if needed for performance.

My question is what would the best practice, to build up the communication between my Flask application and Node.js? Is this a bad idea to set it up like this?

Comment: Did you ever move forward with this? I recently had a similar idea and was wondering how much of a pain it would be. Personally I just feel like node.js/(flask/bottle/pesto) would be a near ideal dev environment.

Comment: There seem to be little support for this and I have not pursued it any further yet.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a really good reason to use both, and you've verified through some benchmarking that using both is necessary, I wouldn't do it. It adds a lot of complexity (code duplication, different libraries working differently in different languages, etc) for questionable benefit.

WebSocket is an issue in Flask, but [you can use Juggernaut to handle it easily](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/80/).

Comment: I want to ping several external wss urls such as the ones offered by GDAX and binance straight from my python flask application, i am a newbie in python and have searched high and low and havent found a decent socket IO client that lets me fetch stream data from multiple urls at the same time in an asychronous manner, i have heard about tornado but seems like connecting with flask is a frowned upon idea, not sure about asyncio integration with flask, i am using celery currently, all i want to do is run my socket client inside celery tasks